# Adjoint representation as derivative of adjoint map

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tangent-spaces

Question: Let $G$ be a Lie group, how can we associate
$$T_e(\text{Aut}(T_eG)) = \text{Der}(T_eG)$$

My motivation for this question is this particular part from my representation theory lecture:

We define a map
$$\text{AD}_g: G \to G, \quad h \mapsto ghg^{-1}$$
And define the adjoint map as its derivation at $e \in G$:
$$\text{Ad}_g := D(\text{AD}_g)_e: T_eG \to T_eG$$
Which can be viewed as a map
$$\text{Ad}: G \to \text{Aut}(T_eG),\quad g \mapsto \text{Ad}_g$$
This is a representation of G and thus implies a representation on the Lie algebra:
$$\text{ad} := D(\text{Ad})_e : T_eG \to T_e(\text{Aut}(T_eG)) = \text{Der}(T_eG)$$
The reason for my question arises at the last step

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! Could you please post a link to your lecture notes, if they are available online?

Answer (score 0):

This can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) in wikipedia, for example.